# Error on test with two diferents EventEmitters on Jamine (Isolated Test)

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, subscribe, eventemitter

I have a class that I need to test and it has two services that use two different EventEmitters (event import and @angular/core). The problem is that if I import one of these EventEmitters I can't import the other but with only one EventEmitter the test fails.

**This is my component code**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-mug",
  templateUrl: "./mug.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mug.component.scss"],
})
export class MugComponent implements OnInit
{
  @Output() nav: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  public mug: Mug= new Mug();

  constructor(
    public constants: Constants,
    public mugService: mugService,
    public basicService: BasicService,
    public toolsService: ToolsService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
  ) 
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.basicService.siteChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.mugService.filterC.id = value;
      this.mugService.getRelatedMugs(); 
    });
  }

  public openModal(contentType: string): void {
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.addListener("close-modal", () =>
      this.toolsService.eventEmitter.removeAllListeners()
    );
    this.toolsService.eventEmitter.addListener(
      "contentEvent",
      (content) => {
        this.setContent(contentType, content);
      }
    );
    const data = {
      component: ModalSearchComponent,
      input: inputList,
      ModalTitle: "Mug finder",
    };
    const modalC = this.modalService.open(ModalContainerComponent, {
      size: "lg",
      backdrop: "static",
    });
    modalC.componentInstance.showComponent(data);
  }
}
```

**This is my Spec.ts code**

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
//import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

describe("MugComponent", () => {
  let component;
  const constants: Constants = new Constants();
  let mugService = jasmine.createSpyObj("mugService", [
    "filterC",
    "getRelatedMugs",
  ]);
  let modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj("modalService", ["open"]);
  let basicService = jasmine.createSpyObj("basicService", [ "siteChange"]);
  let toolsService = jasmine.createSpyObj("toolsService", ["toRoute"], {
    eventEmitter: new EventEmitter(),
  });
  //It needs a different import of EventEmitter
  //basicService.siteChange = new EventEmitter<number>(null);

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new MugComponent(
      constants,
      mugService,
      basicService,
      toolsService,
      modalService,
    );
    component.mug = new Mug();

  });

  it("should call getRelatedMugs", fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(mugService.getRelatedMugs).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

//this also fail with modalC.componentInstance
  it("should call setContent openModal", fakeAsync(() => {
    component.openModal();
    tick();
    expect(component.setContent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

**These are the errors**

```
HeadlessChrome 102.0.5005 (Windows 10.0.0) MugComponent Comprobamos ngOnInit FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

HeadlessChrome 102.0.5005 (Windows 10.0.0) MugComponent Comprobando openModal FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'componentInstance')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading property `subscribe` of undefined is because `siteChange` is not mocked correctly.

When you do:

```
let basicService = jasmine.createSpyObj<BasicService>("basicService", [ "siteChange"]);
```

You are saying that `siteChange` is a public method but in this case it is a property. Also, notice the `<BasicService>` generic supplied, doing so well help you catch errors.

For a quick unblock, try this:

```
let basicService = { siteChange: of('1') };
```

For reading `componentInstance` of undefined, make modal.open return what is required.

```
let modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj("modalService", ["open"]);
// Mock here or before the openModal is called
modalService.open.and.returnValue({
  componenntInstance: {
     showComponent: () => null,
  }
});
....
component = new MugComponent(
      constants,
      mugService,
      basicService,
      toolsService,
      modalService,
    );
```

**Edit**

You need to mock the `toolsService` differently, I am not sure if `new EventEmitter()` has those methods that are being called.

Mock like this:

```
let toolsService = jasmine.createSpyObj("toolsService", ["toRoute"], {
    eventEmitter: {
      addListener: () => null,
      removeAllListeners: () => null,
      // keep adding all the rest you need
    }
  });
```

If you're new, I highly recommend for you to take your time and read this resource, it should help you a lot: https://testing-angular.com/.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm novice on this and you helped me very much.

Comment: Sorry for asking you again, but this line doesn't pass the test, Is it because there is an anonymous function?
this.toolsService.eventEmitter.addListener("close-modal", () =>
      this.toolsService.eventEmitter.removeAllListeners()
    );

Comment: Check out my edit.

Comment: I'm afraid this time it didn't work. The EventEmitter() (imported from events) does have those functions but Jasmine does not enter the anonymous ones inside, not even with the version you have provided me. I'm going to check the link you gave me to see if I can find a solution for those anonymous functions.
Thank you very much again, you are great.